# zf2 skeleton app, convert everything to https

Tags: http, security, https, zend-framework2

I would like to know if there is a quick way to convert an existing zend framework 2 app based on zf2 skeleton to full `https`? as the moment everthing is on `http` include ajax requests

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest and most secure ways to do this is to permanently redirect all incoming traffic/requests for `http` to `https`.

You can do this by adding a redirect rule to your virtual host for port 80. Check [this answer on **security.stackexchange.com**](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22838/is-a-forced-rewrite-from-http-to-https-secure-what-does-sslrequiressl-add/22852#22852) for details on how you can do this.

You should consider referring to `security.stackexchange.com` for posts on this topic. This StackExchange site is not the right place for these kind of security questions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the perfect solution but there are some couple of modules from [zfmodules.com](https://zfmodules.com/) with some features

- https://zfmodules.com/samsonasik/ForceHttpsModule
- https://zfmodules.com/stefanorg/JHttps

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have done just this on a project that uses multiple sites, some http, others https.

In your module.config you will need to add added a route listener to the onBootstrap function.

```
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
...

    $eventManager = $event->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, array($this, 'onRoute'), -100);
```

and add the onRoute function.

```
public function onRoute(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        $uri = $event->getRequest()->getUri();
        $scheme = $uri->getScheme();
        if ($scheme !== 'https') {
            $uri->setScheme('https');
            $response = $event->getResponse();
            $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', $uri);
            $response->setStatusCode(302);
            $response->sendHeaders();
            $event->stopPropagation(true);
        }
    }
```

This will force all http requests to redirect to https.

I hope this helps.